# How to correct sort domain class by an alphanumeric (String) property?

Tags: oracle, hibernate, grails

When I'm sorting a Domain Class by an alphanumeric property, the sort order is not the expected when the value starts with numbers. Example:

```
class MyDomainClass {
  String descr
}

MyDomainClass.createCriteria().list() {
  order("descr", "asc")
}.each { it ->
  println it.descr
}
```

if the table constains this 3 values:

- AAA
- 111
- BBB

The print result is:

- AAA
- BBB
- 111

But what I want is (same as database query result):

- 111
- AAA
- BBB

Is there any configuration where I can define this?

Comment: This would be a matter of setting the right collation on the column at the database level, rather than anything you configure from the Grails side.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I checked the sys.nls_session_parameters table through the Grails Application, and I realized the nls_sort is defined as "WEST_EUROPEAN", so that's the problem. My database default nls_sort is "BINARY". Apparently, this is happening when I change the Application's Locale to "pt_BR". So now I'm triyng to realize how to change the Locale without changing the nls_sort session variable.

Comment: I do not know how to do in sql. But you can write your own comparator to sort the java objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized the problem was happening due to [NLS_SORT parameter](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/initparams130.htm#REFRN10127) on Oracle DB being changed to `WEST_EUROPEAN` when my application sets the locale to `pt_BR` (because this is the default sorting for this locale [according Oracle's documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e10729/applocaledata.htm#i634428)). So I realized I can define a custom sorter using [NLSSORT](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions099.htm) function when necessary:

```
select ret
  from ( select 'AAA' as ret from dual
          union
         select '111' as ret from dual
          union
         select 'BBB' as ret from dual)
 ORDER BY NLSSORT(ret, 'NLS_SORT = BINARY');
```

In grails:

```
println ' --- With WEST_EUROPEAN sort ---'
MyDomain.executeQuery("SELECT m FROM MyDomain as m ORDER BY NLSSORT(descr, 'NLS_SORT = WEST_EUROPEAN')").each {
    println it.descr
}

println ' -- With BINARY sort ---'
MyDomain.executeQuery("SELECT m FROM MyDomain as m ORDER BY NLSSORT(descr, 'NLS_SORT = BINARY')").each {
  println it.descr
}
```

Output:

```
--- With WEST_EUROPEAN sort ---  
AAA  
BBB  
111  
--- With BINARY sort ---  
111  
AAA  
BBB
```